# Convert Date string in timestamp

Tags: bash, date, syntax

I can't find the right syntax to convert a string date in epoch timestamp.

The script is:

```
date -d '2012-03-02 22:00 EDT' +%s
DATEJ=`echo -n \'2012-03-02 22:00\'`
echo $DATEJ
date -d $DATEJ EDT +%s
```

and the result is

```
[gg@raspi8 ~]$ CNVDATTS
1330740000  
'2012-03-02 22:00'  
date: opérande supplémentaire « EDT »  
Saisissez « date --help » pour plus d'informations.
```

Where is the fault?

It seems that the variable `DATEJ` does not give the same as the string in the 1st line. If I don't write `EDT`, the error is same but mention `+%s`.

Comment: What type of Unix are you running on?

Comment: what's the point of the `echo -n`?  why not just `DATEJ='2012-03-02 22:00'`?   Also, you need double-quotes when you use $DATEJ - e.g. `date -d "$DATEJ EDT" +%s`, otherwise `date` will get three arguments `$DATEJ`, `EDT`, and `+%s` instead of two....that's why it's complaining about the extra argument (i don't speak or read french but i can make an uneducated guess :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be with the single-quotes in **`$DATEJ`**. Your variable imposes them.

Change that to

```
DATEJ=`echo -n "2012-03-02 22:00"`
```

and in the final command:

```
date -d "$DATEJ EDT" +%s
```

This will work:

```
$ date -d '2012-03-02 22:00 EDT' +%s
1330740000
$ DATEJ=`echo -n "2012-03-02 22:00"`
$ echo $DATEJ
2012-03-02 22:00
$ date -d "$DATEJ EDT" +%s
1330740000
```

### EDIT

Actually, you don't need to `echo` the date, unless your script imposes so, so the variable **`$DATEJ`** can simply be put as

```
DATEJ="2012-03-02 22:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following will help you or someone else looking for solution.

The date string can be of format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz` or any equivalent. For ex: `"06/10/2021 21:00:00 EST"` or `"06/10/2021 09:00:00 EST"`
TZ data is optional.

You can give the following command to get epoch timestamp:

`date -d "06/10/2021 00:00:00 EST" +"%s"`

OR

you can pass the string in a variable, for ex:

```bsh
date_string="06/10/2021 00:00:00 EST"
date -d "$date_string" +"%s"
```

For your specific problem, following should work:

```bsh
date -d '2012-03-02 22:00 EDT' +%s
DATEJ=`echo -n "2012-03-02 22:00"`
echo $DATEJ
date -d "$DATEJ EDT" +%s
```